# How to accept input from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I am attempting to implement a model view presenter pattern in C# windows forms. I have tried several different methods but have not figured this out.  Is there anyway to "accept" user input from a text box when the user clicks off of the text box? If there is not, what is the typical way to pass data to the presenter? I can use the textbox's on_text_changed event but then I am confused on how to validate the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think its easy here are the **MSDN** links that illustrate the function of `TextBox` class with code.

[**TextBoxBase.Text Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6w057xy.aspx)

& validate using:
[**Control.Validated Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a way too old but still.

```
public interface IProjectView
{
    string textBoxText{get;}
}
```

implement it in ProjectView

```
public class ProjectView : IProjectView
{
    ProjectPresenter _presenter;

    public ProjectView()
    {
        _presenter = new ProjectPresenter(this);
    }

    string textBoxText
    {
        get
        {
            // Do validation if you want
            return textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}


class ProjectPresenter
{
    IProjectView _view;
    public ProjectPresenter(IProjectView view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    public void AnyMethod()
    {
        // Access value of textbox as _view.txtTextBoxText
    }
}
```

Code not tested, but should work fine.

Regarding validation, while implementing the property in ProjectView, do the validation before returning value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to listen for the `Leave` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx). That'll happen when the textbox loses focus; after that, you can do your validation.